# How to realize a data monitor in VHDL?

Tags: signals, vhdl, monitor

I don't know how to describe it exactly, but maybe something like this?

```
void monitor_thread(void)
{
    for(;;){
        if (data==10){
            data=0;
            data2++;
        }
    }
}
```

For me, I'll realize it this way in VHDL:

```
signal data,data2:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
...
process(data)
begin
    case data is:
        when "0101" => data2<=data2+1;
        when others =>
    end case;
end process;
```

But it will cause warnings when compiling in quartus II. I think this is not the proper way to do this. Any suggestions?

Warnings:

```
Warning (10492): VHDL Process Statement warning at xxx: signal "data2" is read inside the Process Statement but isn't in the Process Statement's sensitivity list
Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at xxx: inferring latch(es) for signal or variable "data", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process
```

Comment: I afraid, it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: Without `data2` in the sensitivity list you are creating latches on `data2` with enables derived from values on `data`.  Depending on placement and routing that may not be safe even if `data` is registered - you could increment `data2` when between other values on `data`. It would seem you should be using a clocked process. And as Eugene Sh. notes you aren't providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) making the point of all this clear to craft a solution you can use.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm trying to create a monitor for the data that when a signal becomes a certain value, it will force the signal to a new value. Something like an asynchronous clear signal for a counter when it reaches 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume first, that `data` is a register which is updated at the rising-edge of the clock `clock`. Then `data` will only change once per clock cycle, so that, we need it to compare to the target value also only once per clock cycle. This is achieved by another clocked process which increments `data2` synchronous to `clock`:

```
process (clock)
begin
  if rising_edge (clock) then
    if data = x"0101" then 
      data2  <= data2 + 1; -- data2 of type unsigned, signed, or integer 
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

If `data` is the output of some combinational logic, where the inputs of this combinational logic are registers clocked by `clock`, then `data` may change several times during the clock period. But, you can actually rely only on the settled value because the intermediate values depend on the real delay within the hardware and are thus not deterministic. For monitoring, you can use the same process as above.

If `data` depends on some asynchronous inputs, then you will have to synchronize these inputs first using a common clock. Then the solution from above can be applied.

Comment: Thanks. So I can't have an asynchronous monitor. Did I get you?

Comment: Is this right or not: process means synchronous actions, asynchronous parts should be realized outside a process.

Comment: @Ben only a clocked process means synchronous behaviour, but even this one can have an asynchronous reset. You will always have to wait until a signal change has settled, so it is hard to tell how an asynchronous monitor should work.